# How to go from generator to $\sigma$-field in this case?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Here is the problem:

> $\mathcal{S}\subset\mathcal{P}(\mathbb R)$ has the following property: $$\forall n\in\mathbb N \ \ \ \forall E\in\mathcal{S}: \ \ \ (n+E)\in \mathcal{S} $$ Show that $\sigma(\mathcal{S})$ has the same property: $$\forall n\in\mathbb N \ \ \ \forall E\in\sigma(\mathcal{S}): \ \ \ (n+E)\in \sigma(\mathcal{S})$$

I have tried the standard approach:

1. Choose some property which subsets of $\mathbb R$ can have,
2. Show that $\mathcal{A}:=\{ E\subset \mathbb R \ | \ E \text{ has the property}\}$ is a $\sigma$-field,
3. Show that $\mathcal{S}\subset \mathcal{A}$,
4. Conclude that all elements of $\sigma(\mathcal{S})$ have this property.

The way we described $\mathcal{S}$ seems to be recursive, so one can't write $$\mathcal{S}:= \{ E\subset\mathbb R \ | \ \forall n\in \mathbb N: (n+E)\in \mathcal{S} \}$$

And defining $$\mathcal{A}:=\{ E\subset\mathbb R \ | \ \forall n\in \mathbb N: E\in\mathcal{S} \implies (n+E)\in \mathcal{S} \}$$
seems to be okay for steps $(1)$ to $(3)$ but isn't helpful for the conclusion in $(4)$.

So what would be the property from $(1)$ in this case?